# Which is faster in my case, 28800 queries to mysql or 28800 iterations of a large array..?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays, performance

So I've been developing an application that needs to compare a lot of data. The max (I'm assuming) at once will be about 28800 rows that need to be compared against another table separately.

So what I'm doing right now is making 28800 ajax calls to a database and it works, but it's obviously not the fastest procedure in the world.

Would it be faster to iterate over an array of about say, 80,000 elements 28800 times and just making 2 db calls?

I'm assuming it is not, but just figured I'd ask to be sure.

For a little background knowledge, check out an earlier question I posted: 
[How to avoid out of memory error in a browser due to too many ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334933/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-in-a-browser-due-to-too-many-ajax-calls/22337715?noredirect=1#comment34025515_22337715)

Thank you!

Comment: Well, 28800 AJAX calls to run one query each would almost certainly be slower than iterating through an array and making 2 DB calls... or why not just letting 1 AJAX call handle all 28800 queries if they must be done individually? 28800 AJAX calls seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you're trying to do... but databases are meant for manipulating data.  If you're just trying to join a couple tables, you should let the database take care of that heavy lifting for you in most cases.

Comment: How do you mean 1 AJAX call to handle all 28800 queries? 

And I know, it is definitely a horrible idea - hence why I've been trying to find an alternative.

Comment: Smells like a wrong architecture. Have you studied DB/OOP patterns?

Comment: @Brad I'm comparing two tables of data with different points.. i.e., one stores sun radiation at a certain lat long (has about 300,000 rows) and the other stores aspect (direction the area is facing). So I would want to check for all radiation above 4500, with a south facing aspect (between 157.5 and 202.5)... 

EDIT: and they have different lat longs cause they're different resolutions (ones every 5km and the other is 10km data)

Comment: @MoTawakol That sounds like something you would absolutely leave up to the database and do in a single query.

Comment: @djay a little, but probably not enough.. they way it's set up is mostly in the link if you have a better setup in mind I'd love to learn!

Comment: 28,800 TCP connections. 28,800 DB connections, 28,800 queries. Slow, no matter HOW you go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some very specific reason you are making that many calls it sounds like thre must be an easier way to retrieve all this data, have the database do some of the work, or rethink what is happening.

1. Can you write a database script that is passed some params and does the comparison?
2. Chances are the database can work faster than looping over all that data 28800 times as the database uses other methods for comparing and retrieving data. You are in a way comparing brute force looping to a database engine.
3. Can your write a query that does the comparison?
4. It sounds like you are pulling the data and then doing more work to it, can you pull the data you need with a single query?

Comment: I can't because the points are different. so if I have a lat long from one table, I won't find that exact lat long in the other table, I need to pull all the lat/longs within 10 km of that one and check if they have the proper attribute and return the ones that do, map them and move on to the next point

Comment: Can you do something along the lines of 

Select *
From LATLONG1
Where distance(lat1,long1,secondtable.lat2,secondtable.long2) < 10 && attribute = desiredAttribute 

where distance is a function that calculates the distance between latlong1 and latlong2 from the 2 tables

take a look at this 
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: A query like that would find all points that seem to fit what you are looking for, or you could put that in a database script and just call that script from the front end.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know my lat longs until I query the first table and receive the 28,800 rows of data. And then I need to check against each row separately and send that result to another function.

Comment: I understand that you do not know them until you run the query but assuming the tables are in the same database (or even on the same network) you can pull information from both of them in a single script, or join then on a clause that will return the correct result.

Comment: Did not know that.. I'll do some more research.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general rule that I haver found is that MySQL is massively fast on doing simple queries, especially when indexed, and abominably slow on complex ones involving multiple joins or nested sub queries.

This doesn't actually answer your question though, because its too vague. Mysql retrieval is critical with respect to what indexes are applied. It is also critical to the complexity of the query.

So there are no general rules. You must try both and see which is better.

Likewise javascript performance varies wildly between browsers.

A final comment: some things that are simple to define in procedural code, like checking the result of one query to formulate the shape of the next, are massively easier to code than to work out what exactly the optimal SQL syntax should be to combine them into a single query, and even then, you may find that the mysql server is building massive temporary tables to do it.