# "Insufficient resources error" when making repeated ajax requests from Chrome console

Tags: javascript, getjson

I have this javascript code that is meant to run inside the google chrome console. It constantly checks a json formatted response. If anywhere in the response BestPrice equals max_price then it will purchase it using some API. The problem I am having is about 10 seconds after running it I get 'ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES'.

I suppose it is from too many requests? I need it to loop through as fast as possible, so if it can't be instant, is there a certain request limit?

**Code:**

```
function snipebot(page, max_page, max_price){
    $.getJSON('http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&PageNumber=' + page, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            if (item['BestPrice'] <= max_price){
                $.get('http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?id=' + item['AssetId'], function(data){
                    var purchaseData = $($(data).find(".PurchaseButton")[0]).data();
                    if (purchaseData['expectedPrice'] <= item['BestPrice']){
                        $.post('/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + purchaseData['productId'] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + '&expectedSellerId=' + purchaseData['expectedSellerId'] + '&userAssetID=' + purchaseData['userassetId'], function(){
                            console.log('[' + item['BestPrice'] + '] @' + new Date().toTimeString())    
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Detected purchase.");
                    }
                });
            };
            setTimeout(function(){
                snipebot(page + 1 > max_page ? 1 : page + 1, max_page, max_price);
            },100);
            console.log("!checked");
        });
    });
};
snipebot(1, 4, 50);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334933/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-in-a-browser-due-to-too-many-ajax-calls or in short, group your requests and make a single or at least fewer calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `snipebot`, it makes a request, and looking at the URL you're using, it gets an array back. Then for each item in the array, you are spawning another `snipebot` call. Each of those calls would in turn spawn more `snipebot` calls and so on. So, yeah, the `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` error isn't really surprising.

Comment: This does not answer why `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES ` is caused in the first place. So what that repeated ajax calls are made? What is the limit? How is it determined?

Comment: I think what the original poster was trying to do was to iterate through 4 pages of products looking for the cheapest. But he made a mistake. Instead of making 4 web requests, one for each page, he was making thousands. Eventually his PC ran out of memory.